# Getting error when running gulp serve

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

So I've I'm trying to setup a develop-enviroment where I'm using gulp.

However, after installing all dependencies I get this error:

```
Hariss-MacBook-Pro:teacher haris$ gulp serve
[19:00:28] Using gulpfile ~/teacher/gulpfile.js
[19:00:28] Starting 'statics'...
[19:00:28] Finished 'statics' after 1.92 ms
[19:00:28] Starting 'jshint'...
[19:00:28] Starting 'clean-css'...
[19:00:28] Starting 'templates'...
[19:00:28] Server started on 3000 port
[19:00:28] Finished 'clean-css' after 12 ms
[19:00:28] Starting 'styles'...
[19:00:28] Finished 'templates' after 35 ms
[19:00:28] Finished 'jshint' after 336 ms
Assertion failed: (val->IsString()), function _NanGetExternalParts, file ../node_modules/nan/nan.h, line 1725.
Abort trap: 6
Hariss-MacBook-Pro:teacher haris$
```

I first though it was some kind of issue with specificly windows so I tryed it on my Mac but the same error occurred.

Do anyone know what this is or can give we a hint on what next to do?

Regards

Comment: Are you using `gulp-sass`? The current version has this issue: https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/57

Comment: Aah it must be! How do i downgrade using npm for specific module? @GergoErdosi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of `gulp-sass` has this [issue](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/57). If you are using it, then downgrade to version 0.7.1. If you have a `package.json` file, then specify the version number:

```
"gulp-sass": "0.7.1"
```

And run `npm install`. If you just used `npm install` without `package.json`, then execute this command:

```
npm install gulp-sass@0.7.1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Works like a charm. Im new at this, you saved me some headaches!